# Working with Forms (POST request to REST API) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have decent backend/frontend experience, but I'm new to Flutter.

I looked at a lot of tutorials, but didn't come up with anything :(

- the tutorials do not use the latest flutter_bloc (<7-8), and the logic structure is fundamentally different there
- the tutorials cover simple actions (clicked on the button - received data from the REST API), but does not say how to interact with forms that send POST / GET data
- the tutorials show how to create a model based on JSON, but what if the JSON structure is different depending on the validation on the backend?

**What I want to achieve (using flutter_bloc 8):**

1. When clicking on "Create post" send a POST request (REST API)
2. If JSON response is status = 'error' - display errors in each field (TextFormField/decoration/errorText:<error_message>)
3. If the JSON response is status = 'success' - go to another screen and display the post from data (post_id, title, content).

P.S. I know that it is possible to validate data without sending a request to the API, but I want to understand the mechanism of how the field is converted (when we forward the data from the JSON response to the errorText).

If someone has time to show step by step how to do this - I would be very grateful, like many other beginners.

**JSON structure (status='error'):**

```
{
   "status":"error",
   "errors":{
      "title":[
         "Title can't be empty"
      ],
      "content":[
         "Post content can't be empty"
      ]
   }
}
```

**JSON structure (status='success'):**

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "post_id":321,
      "title":"Test title",
      "content":"Test content"
   }
}
```

**create_post_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreatePostScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CreatePostScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Post title',
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Post content',
                  ),
                  minLines: 5,
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Create post'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Initial screen**

[image]

**Display errors from API response (if status='error')**

[image]

Comment: You need to use packages like http or dio to do api calls and based on those states you can show success/error message

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `status` field for your state maybe something like this

```
    enum LoadingStatus {
        loading,
        idle, 
        error,
        success
    }
    
    class Status {
        final LoadingStatus status;
        final String error;
    
        Status(this.status, this.error);
     }
```

2. Create a state with a statuses map and the key would be the textfield's title so `{'post title': Status}`

```
class CreatePostState {
  const CreatePostState(this.statuses);

  final Map<String, Status> statuses;
  //and whatever fields you need
  CreatePostState copyWith(
      {Map<String, Status> statuses}){
        return CreatePostState(statuses);
      }
}
```

3. Your bloc event would look something like this

```
    try {
      statuses = state.statuses;
      statuses['Post Title'] = Status(LoadingStatus.loading);
      emit(CreatePostState(statuses));
      await api.call()
      statuses['Post Title'] = Status(LoadingStatus.success);
      emit(CreatePostState(statuses));
    } catch (e) {
      statuses['Post Title'] = Status(LoadingStatus.error);
      emit(CreatePostState(statuses));

    }
```

4. add `BlocProvider` and `BlocBuilder` as parent to `Scaffold`